# React - Display text messages in sections

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, components

I need to display text messages in sections:

Messages received today, messages received yesterday, messages received this week, messages received this month, and keep going in month intervals after that...

Example:

[image]

My attempt:

Dashboard.js

```
import React from "react"
import MessageList from "./MessageList"

export default class Dashboard extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      messages: [
            {
                id: "1",
                body: "Hello",
                date: "2017-04-22T09:25:50",

            },
            {
                id: "2",
                body: "Hello",
                date: "2017-04-21T04:31:22",

            },
            {
                id: "3",
                body: "How are you?",
                date: "2017-04-21T03:08:31",

            },
            {
                id: "4",
                body: "Meeting soon",
                date: "2017-04-18T01:10:32",

            }
        ]
      }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div id="dashboard">
        <MessageList messages={this.state.messages}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

MessageList.js

```
import React from "react"

export default class MessageList extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  render() {
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var currentDayOfMonth = currentDate.getDate()
    var currentDayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay()
    var timeline = "Today"

    const messageList = this.props.messages.map((message) => {

      var date = message.date.substring(0, 10)
      var time = message.date.slice(12)

      var testDate = new Date(date)
      var testDayOfMonth = testDate.getDate()+1
      var testDayOfWeek = testDate.getDay()

      if(currentDayOfMonth == testDayOfMonth+1){
        timeline = 'Yesterday'
      } else if(currentDayOfMonth > testDayOfMonth+1 && currentDayOfWeek - testDayOfWeek < 6) {
        timeline = 'This week'
      }

        return (
          <div key={message.id}>
            <h2>{timeline}</h2>
            <li className="list-group-item">
              Date: {date} <br></br>
              Time: {time} <br></br>
              Body: {message.body}
            </li>
          </div>
        )
    })

    return (
      <div id="messageList">
        <ul className="list-group">
          {messageList}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

However, my app looks like this:

[image]

The `H2` is being displayed every time. What's the best way to fix this?

Additionally, anyone know a better way to structure the messages in general? I am considering making `subcomponents` for every group: A `component` for Today, a `component` for Yesterday.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, this is how you need to modify your render method:

```
  var currentDate = new Date()
  var currentDayOfMonth = currentDate.getDate()
  var currentDayOfWeek = currentDate.getDay()
  var timeline = "today"

  var mssgTypeList = {
    "today" : [],
    "yesterday" : [],
    "this_week" : []
   }

   this.props.message.forEach(function(message,index){
      var date = message.date.substring(0, 10)
      var time = message.date.slice(12)

      var testDate = new Date(date)
      var testDayOfMonth = testDate.getDate()+1
      var testDayOfWeek = testDate.getDay()

      if(currentDayOfMonth == testDayOfMonth+1){
        timeline = 'yesterday'
      } else if(currentDayOfMonth > testDayOfMonth+1 && currentDayOfWeek - testDayOfWeek < 6) {
        timeline = 'this_week'
      }

      mssgTypeList[timeline].push(message);

   });

   const TodayMessageList = mssgTypeList["today"].map((message) => {
      var date = message.date.substring(0, 10);
      var time = message.date.slice(12);

        return (
            <li className="list-group-item" key={message.id}>
              Date: {date} <br></br>
              Time: {time} <br></br>
              Body: {message.body}
            </li>
        )
   });

   const YesterdayMessageList = mssgTypeList["yesterday"].map((message) => {
      var date = message.date.substring(0, 10);
      var time = message.date.slice(12);

        return (
            <li className="list-group-item" key={message.id}>
              Date: {date} <br></br>
              Time: {time} <br></br>
              Body: {message.body}
            </li>
        ) 
   })

  const WeekMessageList = mssgTypeList["this_week"].map((message) => {
      var date = message.date.substring(0, 10);
      var time = message.date.slice(12);

        return (
            <li className="list-group-item" key={message.id}>
              Date: {date} <br></br>
              Time: {time} <br></br>
              Body: {message.body}
            </li>
        ) 
  })

  return (
      <div id="messageList">

        <h2>Today</h2>
        <ul className="list-group today-group">
          {TodayMessageList}
        </ul>

        <h2>Yesterday</h2>
        <ul className="list-group yesterday-group">
          {YesterdayMessageList}
        </ul>

        <h2>This Week</h2>
        <ul className="list-group week-group">
          {WeekMessageList}
        </ul>

      </div>
    )
```

First you need to separate out messages based on timelines, then showing message on UI based on separate timeline list of messages.

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. My only concern is that ll the MessageList components -- Today, Yesterday, This Week -- are all so repetitive. There is one word difference in code between them. Is there a way to minimize the clutter?

Comment: The problem is when you use map, you return something for every array element. Here in your messageList, all three kind of messages are mixed up. Therefore when you are showing it on UI, you are not sure which type of message you are showing. I could only think to group them together once and then show them one by one.
Not sure, if some other way is there the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a component named "Message".
And then create the list component like:

- YesterdayMessageList (contains only one h2 tag and messages)
- TodayMessageList (contains only one h2 tag and messages)
- ThisWeekMessageList (contains only one h2 tag and messages)

After all, in Dashboard component will include 3 above components.
YesterdayMessageList, TodayMessageList, ThisWeekMessageList